# What type of chili pepper is my plant?

Tags: identification

I have a chili plant but I don't know what type it is? Attached below is a pic to help whoever answers this question.

[image: small plant with four peppers. 3 Red. 1 Redish dark greenish]

Comment: Do your recall "Thai Chili Pepper"?

Comment: There are too many varieties to tell you. It should be the variety the seller told you. Hybridization is very common, so possibly it is not a variety (a variety should have a name and a description, but also be genetically stable. Children of most hybrids will not look like the parents plants. -- On the other hand, the variety seldom matter. Try it, and see what it is the best use for it.

Comment: Note: flowers help to identify them (I'm not an expert, and I do not go to variety exposition since years). This is particular because of hairs on stem (aubergine like habit)